# Moving 2 different SharePoint2013 servers to one installation

Tags: sharepoint-server, server-farm, domain, development-enviroment, merge

We have 2 different SharePoint 2013 servers installation in our organization.
One runs on "http//production-portal" and other runs "http//test-portal". Due to some problems with production-portal, the test-portal is working perfect and we want to move the SharePoint 2013 to production-portal as we have only 1 SharePoint 2013 license (cannot afford two licenses). How can I do this? 
Both are different farms with different installation but on the same network.

Kindly help me to move my test server into production or merge both under same domain address.

The "http//test-portal" is on the trial development license.

Answer (score 0):

It is depend upon how you configure the your farm.Here the steps you can perform to merge both farms.

1. Make sure both farms are same patch level.
2. Same Solutions / Customization deployed to both farm(if any)
3. Destination must have the Web Application with correct Authentication Configured.
4. Move the Content Database From Source to Destination farm.
5. Attach the content Database to Web app(s)
6. Update the AAM
7. COnfigure the DNS Properly so that it points to correct server.(usauly it took 2 hours to publish on internet.)
8. Run full search crawl and User Profile Crawl.
9. Test now.